# How do I find out where the contents of a package are installed?

Tags: package-management, apt

I ran into [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdeedu/+bug/766061), where Cantor can't find the sage backend if both are installed through the ubuntu package system. I can get around this bug if I know the path to the sage executable, but even after installing cantor-backend-sage I can't figure out where sage is located. `locate` and `find` both return loads of files called `message`-something, and have been unhelpful. `which sage` and `whereis sage` return nothing.

Is there some way to figure out where apt-get installs everything in a package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which files were installed by package? `dpkg -L package`.
Which files will package install? `apt-file list -F package`.

Also the other direction is possible:

Which package installed this file? `dpkg -S file`
Which package do I need to install for file? `apt-file search file`.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use apt-get but dpkg:

```
dpkg -L package-name
```